# Suggest a safe command to delete files after a script used it

Tags: rm

I have this script where I would like to add a line that, after the concatenation, safely deletes the *.dump files, because they are big and I have no space for the concatenated files and the dump files.
jelly is a txt that have a list of genomes ids one by line like:

```
GCA....
GCA....and so on.
```

The I have a bunch of dump files name after genomes ids with two columns:
ex. GCA...1.dump that is like:

```
A 57575757
C 6656565..
```

ex. GCA...2.dump that is like:

```
AA 6565656
AT 6565656...
```

So I have 14 dump files for each genome id (1-14 ngrams). So, I want to concatenate all 1-14 for each genome id and then delete the used dump files based in the jelly file. And at end I want just one file named *.counts at the created new directory.

```
#! usr/bin/env bash

dir_in=$1 # Jelly_count
super=$2 # Archaea/Bacteria
group=$3 # Asgard_group/Pseudomonadota
sub=$4 # Aquificota
dir_out=Counts/"${super}"/"${group}"/"${sub}"/CHR

if [ ! -d "${dir_out}" ]; then
  mkdir -p "${dir_out}"
fi
# read the ids in jelly file
for id in $(cat "${dir_in}"/"${super}"/"${group}"/"${sub}"/jelly);
do
  echo "Concatenating files from genome ${id}"
  # make a loop from 1 to 14 or any other range I need
  for i in $(seq $5 $6);
    do
      # concatenate all 14 tsv files in one
      csvtk concat "${dir_in}"/"${super}"/"${group}"/"${sub}"/CHR/"${id}"_"${i}".dump >> "${dir_out}"/"${id}"_chr_kmer.counts
     # then delete all the 14 dump files
     # MAYBE ?????
     **find "${dir_in}"/"${super}"/"${group}"/"${sub}". -name '*.dump' -delete**
    done
    
done
```

I tried rm, but there are a better way?

Thank you all.

Paulo

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example how you run your script, copy&paste a few lines of the file `.../jelly`, show what input files you have, what files you want to create and what files you want to delete. Do you have to run `csvtk concat` in a loop or could you specify several files to concatenate in one command?  Can there be other files with numbers outside the range specified by `seq $5 $6`? Do you want to ignore and delete these files?

Comment: @Bodo If you have a better way and easy way to do, I would appreciate any idea. Thank you.

Comment: Please copy&paste **real example data** instead of typing something with `....` or `....and so on.` and list the corresponding file names. You did not show an example command line. I still did not understand what files are the expected output files, what contents you expect in the output file based on the input. I try to understand how command line arguments and file contens correspond to the existing files. If you don't answer *all* my questions it is difficult to help. The example file name `GCA...1.dump` neither matches the pattern `"${id}"_"${i}".dump` nor your input file `GCA....`

Comment: BTW: Automatically deleting your input data is dangerous. If something fails you may lose your input data without having the resulting output.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do in batch...thak you

Comment: It is bad idea to `-delete` files in a script without checking the exit status of previous commands. I prefer `cat "file${i}" >> accumulator  &&  rm "file${i}"`  over `find ...*.dump -delete` which can delete more files that are dumped.

Comment: Currently, you are doing  something like `for i=1,2,3; do copy file$i; find ... file* -delete; done` which copies only the first file and the deletes all three (or 14 or how many you have)

Comment: I do not see any use for [csvtk concat](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/usage/#concat) here especially that I see no headers in your files. Also using `csvtk concat`  with one argument is strange. And using `>> somefile` would be bad if csvtk produces any header on the output. May be you want tu use just ordinary unix command `cat` ?

Comment: csvtk worked fine and the 14 file has 60MB and has 3517586 lines... so it is a very large file. And

Comment: @Paulo, by concatenating 14 files of 60 MB you save on order of 13kB. You may consider some sort of compression. `gzip` or `bzip2`. Can be used together with `tar`. (alternatively `zip` or `pkzip` or `7z` if you are used to that). You may search for "How to compress files with tar"

Comment: @Paulo, I looked again at `csvtk concat`. It works for you *because* you put a single file there. It takes first line as a header and copies it to output. Then it copies the remaining line. Were it that you specified a second file, it would read first line as a header, analyse it and discard it. Then it would discard part (all!) of the lines below because your unintended "headings" do not match.

Comment: @minorChaos It did worked with headers too. It read the first file add every line, then read the second file and because >> to the count file, it keeping adding lines from the second file and so on at the end of the new file (counts). A 661121
C 1352521
G 1347429
T 655876
AA 118560
AC 190523
AG 212933
AT 139105
CA 224801
CC 388494
CG 527914
CT 211312
GA 268995
GC 504067
GG 386122
GT 188245
TA 48765
TC 269437
TG 220459
TT 117214

Comment: @minorChaos it looks like csvtk doesnt discard any line because I have ACGT, then all 16 dinucleotides (AA AC AG AT...)

Comment: @Paulo I said `It works for you because....`, so we agree on that it works for you (with a single line on the comand-line). What about using `gzip` / `bzip2` ... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148195/discussion-between-minorchaos-and-paulo-sergio-schlogl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all I can guess the original is meant to be run as

```
 myscript   Jelly_count  Archaea/Bacteria Asgard_group/Pseudomonadota Aquificota 1 14
```

May preference is  `cat "$ff" >> "$F" && rm "$ff"` where I first set `ff` to be the name of the file.

I would try the following.
I hope there are not many/any typos there.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This file is named   script1

set -e    # exit on most errors. (This may be safer.)

dir_in="$1"    # Jelly_count
super="$2"     # Archaea/Bacteria
group="$3"     # Asgard_group/Pseudomonadota
sub="$4"      # Aquificota

#   $5  $6     means take counts from $5 to $6

dir_out=Counts/"${super}"/"${group}"/"${sub}"/CHR

if [ ! -d "${dir_out}" ]; then
  mkdir -p "${dir_out}"
fi
# read the ids in jelly file
for id in $(cat "${dir_in}"/"${super}"/"${group}"/"${sub}"/jelly);
do
  echo "Concatenating files from genome ${id}"
  # make a loop from 1 to 14 or any other range I need
  F="${dir_out}"/"${id}"_chr_kmer.counts
  if [ -e "$F" ]; then
       echo "File $F already exists, I do not like that";
       # exit; # the safest
       echo "<ENTER> to skip this and continue; <Ctrl-C> to stop";
       read
       # # An alternative: leave the file be and `continue`
       continue
       # # An alternative:
       # mv "$F" "$F"-old-"$(date)"-$$
       # # Alternative2 : just print warning:
       # echo "File $F already exists, we will make it even bigger!"
       # # Alternative3 : delete file
       # echo "File $F already exists, I am deleting it now."
       # rm "$F"
  fi
  for i in $(seq $5 $6);
    do
      ff="${dir_in}"/"${super}"/"${group}"/"${sub}"/CHR/"${id}"_"${i}".dump
      echo -n "about to delete: "
      wc -l "$ff"  # Print number of lines
      # cat and remove
      cat "$ff" >> "$F" && rm "$ff"
    done
    echo -n "The new file   : "
    wc -l "$F"  # Print number of lines

    echo "<ENTER> to proceed with the next; <Ctrl-C> to stop";
    read

done
```

which would be run again like

```
 script1   Jelly_count  Archaea/Bacteria Asgard_group/Pseudomonadota Aquificota 1 14
```

(Later you can remove the `echo -n` and `wc` lines, and the line couples `echo`+`read`. Here `wc` means word count, `wc -l` is actually line count.)

Comment: Most shells have interpolation, which means you don't have to individually quote the variables in a file path:  `for id in $(cat "${dir_in}/${super}/${group}/${sub}/jelly")` is cleaner without all the double-quotes in the middle.   Also, modern versions of bash support a shortcut syntax for opening and reading a file in Command Substitution, so you don't have to fork/exec `cat`:  `$(< /path/to/file)`

Comment: @Sotto, thank you, both your comments are valid. The line came from original and I did not have strong reasons to modify it. There is a different thing I would change for performance.

Comment: Performance would be improved when the arguments of `cat` in the inner loop would be accumulated to on array. But the difference will is negligible with 14 files of 60MB.